# See any problems with this search-specific homomorphic encoding strategy?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, searchable-encryption

I'm imagining this for use in the scenario of cloud-stored client-encrypted email, where, when seeking to do a string search across messages, you don't want to have to download every stored message in order to decrypt and search.

[Note that inspiration for this approach is taken from [Jones & Mewhort, 2007](http://www.indiana.edu/~clcl/BEAGLE/Jones_Mewhort_PR.pdf); I otherwise assert no formal rights to the algorithm, but appreciate props if it's a good idea : O) ]

Initialization steps:

1. For each unicode character, client generates a D-dimensional vector (where D is large, >1024) where each element is a 64-bit float drawn from a random Gaussian with mean of zero and a standard deviation of `1/sqrt(D)`. Call these the "character vectors".
2. Client also generates a "permutation vector" representing a random permutation of the order of elements 1 through D.
3. All vectors are encrypted and stored by the client for later decryption and use while encrypting messages as described below.

When encrypting a message, a standard strong encryption (RSA, etc) of the message is computed, as well as it's associated "hologram", computed as follows:

1. For every bigram of characters, the associated character vectors are combined via [circular convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution) made non-commutative (and therefore encoding the bigram's character order) by first shuffling the second vector's elements according to the order prescribed by the permutation vector generated during initialization. Thus, if `&` is used to denote this non-commutative circular convolution, then `a&b` is a D-dimensional vector that is very different from (low [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) with) `b&a`.
2. Since all vectors generated in step 1 are D-dimensional, they can be summed to a single vector `H` that holographically encodes the full set of vectors. That is, if `a&b` contributed to `H` but `c&d` did not, then the cosine similarity between `H` and `a&b` will be much greater than the cosine similarity between `H` and `c&d`. This isn't lossless encoding (circular convolution causes data loss, as does the superposition of bigram vectors into a hologram), but it'll be good enough...
3. Now repeat step 1 for all ngrams (up to a reasonable maximum search string length) in the text (i.e. if the text is `abc`, do `a&b`, `b&c`, `(a&b)&c`, `a&(b&c)`), continuing to sum each into `H`. At the end, `H` holographically represents the content of the message.

When done, client sends the encrypted message as well as it's associated hologram to the cloud for storage.

Steps for searching for a given search string:

1. Client computes a hologram for the search string exactly as they would for a regular message
2. Client sends the resulting search string hologram to the server
3. Server computes the cosine similarity between the search string hologram and each message hologram, yielding a rank ordered set of messages, the top X of which are sent back to the client
4. For each message returned from the server, the client decrypts the message and performs a standard plaintext string search.

It's possible that this scheme would get a worthwhile security benefit from having two permutation vectors, one for the left-hand vector and one for the right-hand vector, but I'm not clear yet on whether this would be necessary. I described it using one above for simplicity.

Certainly the initialization would need to be high-entropy, probably avoiding a single random seed, but since it's done only once, this shouldn't be too much of a hardship.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's unclear what your threat model is, and what exactly your computational assumptions are, but I see at least one potential problem, without even considering the direct leakage from your holographic representation.  Search tokens are very mutable in your scheme.  If the adversary gets a token for a and another token for b, they can generate the token a&b.  That's usually a really bad thing.  Also, can you not use the similarity of holograms between two messages to tell how lexicographically "close" they are?

Comment: Since the non-commutative circular convolution involves permutation by a secret index array, an adversary could not compute the search token for `abcxyz` even if given access to the search tokens for `abc` and `xyz`. They can compute message similarities if given access to the database of message holograms, though I can't think of realistic cases under which this could be trouble.